# How to connect local PyCharm to python installed on a server? Is this even possible?

Tags: python, server, pycharm, connect

I have PyCharm on my machine (8GB RAM). I am required to to heavy data processing, and would like to use an institutionally provided server. This server has Python installed, but without any IDE. So all I see is a CUI, and it is difficult to program in such an environment.Also note that I cannot ask server admin to install software on the server for me. So, how can one connect one's local PyCharm to a python installed on a remote server? Is this even possible?

Comment: you could take a look at the following [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-ssh-terminal.html). A professional license is a prerequisite.

Comment: As a note: as a student you can get a "professional" license. https://www.jetbrains.com/student/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure an interpreter using SSH:

1. Open the Add Python Interpreter dialogue
2. In the left-hand pane of the Add Python Interpreter dialogue, click SSH Interpreter.
3. Follow the wizard.

For more detailed instructions, check: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html

**Note:** unfortunately, this option is not available in the PyCharm Community Edition.

Comment: Hey Alexander, thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for I guess, but I'm stuck again. I do not see the SSH option in my Pycharm IDE. What can be done?
Edit: Just realised I have PyCharm Community Version which does not have remote processing capabilities. Thanks again!

Comment: @ShagunTripathi Thank you for letting me know, I have edited the answer to explicitly tell that it would require a paid version of PyCharm